# How to get previous Days, Months, Season from SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, toad

I'm new in Oracle/Toad. 
I'm trying to get previous Days, Month, Seasons from SYSDATE just like this:

```
20190102
20190101
20181231
20181230
20181201
20181101
20181001
20180701
20180401
20180101
20171001
20170701
```

Can someone help me with this ?

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd'),'yyyymmdd'),
       to_date(to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd')-1,'yyyymmdd'), 
       to_date(to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd')-2,'yyyymmdd'), 
       to_date(to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd')-3,'yyyymmdd'),
       trunc(sysdate)-(to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd'))-1)
       from dual;
```

I stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to get previous Days, Month, Seasons from SYSDATE

The logic of your expected date series is unclear, however based on the quote, here are the basic tools to achieve your goal :

```
SELECT 
    trunc(sysdate) - 1 last_day,
    add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) first_day_of_last_month,
    add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Q'), -3) first_day_of_last_quarter
FROM DUAL
```

Yields :

```
  LAST_DAY  | FIRST_DAY_OF_LAST_MONTH | FIRST_DAY_OF_LAST_QUARTER
  :-------- | :---------------------- | :------------------------
  06-JAN-19 | 01-DEC-18               | 01-OCT-18
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0e949866d46e6117139210f61071ca7d)*